# Bind element inside of datatemplate to parent's property

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

how can i bind an element inside of a template to a property of its parent like:

```
<Button Tag="rofl">
   <Button.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{ HERE I WANT TO BIND TO THE BUTTONS TAG }"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Pedro Lamas's answer you can also perform this by the following way:

```
        <Button x:Name="ButtonTemplate" Tag="rofl">
            <Button.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, ElementName=ButtonTemplate}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Button.ContentTemplate>
        </Button>
```

You define a name for your control and access it's property in it's DataTemplate thanks to the ElementName feature.

Comment: This works fine, thank you. But this is not what I want, because I have to give the button a name and have to implement that for every button. I want to define that in a Style for buttons, so every button behaves like that.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [RelativeSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/relativesource-markup-extension#xaml-attribute-usage-templatedparent-mode) with the `TemplatedParent` to do that:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
```

Comment: The parent template of  `TextBlock` is `ContentPresenter`, you will not find the `Tag` property. You code may not work.